# Keep relationships to closest neighbors

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a graph with structure `(:Person)-[:KNOW]->(:Person)`.
Now a Person node has a latitude and longitude. One Person is connected to 10 other Persons.
For each Person, I want to keep the relationships to only 5 closest Persons. Since the graph is very large, I'm thinking about using `apoc.periodic.iterate`.

Here is what I have now, but I don't know how to Delete the relationships for the last 5 Persons:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n", 
"WITH n
MATCH (n)-[r:KNOW]->(m:Person) 
WITH point({longitude: TOFLOAT(n.long), latitude: TOFLOAT(n.lat)}) AS p1, point({longitude: TOFLOAT(m.long), latitude: TOFLOAT(m.lat)}) AS p2, r 
WITH point.distance(p1, p2) AS Distance, r ORDER BY Distance", 
{batchSize:10000, parallel:false})
```

Could you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you sort (ORDER BY) by distance, you can collect the relationships then get the 6th to the last item of the list. Then you can remove the farthest nodes to n.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n", 
"WITH n
MATCH (n)-[r:KNOW]->(m:Person) 
WITH point({longitude: TOFLOAT(n.long), latitude: TOFLOAT(n.lat)}) AS p1, point({longitude: TOFLOAT(m.long), latitude: TOFLOAT(m.lat)}) AS p2, r, n 
WITH point.distance(p1, p2) AS Distance, n, r ORDER BY n, Distance
WITH n, collect(r)[5..] as farthest_dist 
FOREACH (farthest_r in farthest_dist|DELETE farthest_r)", 
{batchSize:10000, parallel:false})
```

I added n on the sorting because batch_size is 10000 so there are 10k n persons per batch. This notation collect(r)[5..] means put all relationships in a list and give me the 6th item, 7th item, up to the max item. You can also use UNWIND() at the last statement instead of FOREACH(), if you like.

```
UNWIND farthest_dist as farthest_r 
DELETE farthest_r
```

Before you remove the relationships, I would suggest that you backup your database first so that you can restore your data when needed.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on putting `n` after ORDER BY?

Comment: Please always test/debug your code. Copy the whole query, then replace  FOREACH with RETURN at the end. Thx

Comment: If you have 3 rows like n1,r8, 8  n1, r9, 9  n2, r11, 11 and you want to get top row per n, then you will sort by n then by dist NOT  by dist only. If you do order by n, dist then collect(r)[0] = n1, r8 and n2,r11. If you sort by dist only, collect(r)[0] = n1, r8.

Comment: Thanks for replies. But you already put `n` before `collect`. Isn't it enough to group by `n`? I'm talking about this line:
`WITH n, collect(r)[5..] as farthest_dist `

Comment: I highly suggest you test/debug it so that you will see the difference.  Try this:  MATCH (n:Person)
WITH n LIMIT 10 
MATCH (n)-[r:KNOW]->(m:Person) 
WITH point({longitude: TOFLOAT(n.long), latitude: TOFLOAT(n.lat)}) AS p1, point({longitude: TOFLOAT(m.long), latitude: TOFLOAT(m.lat)}) AS p2, r, n 
WITH point.distance(p1, p2) AS Distance, n, r ORDER BY n, Distance
WITH n, collect(r)[5..] as farthest_dist 
RETURN n, farthest_dist

Comment: Then compare it with  ORDER BY Distance WITH collect(r)[5..] as farthest_dist RETURN  farthest_dist

Comment: The former will return you farthest nodes per n while the latter will give you the nodes with largest distances on any nodes.

Comment: I tested both options, and I saw no differences in the result.
Anw, thanks for your solution, which I already accepted, but it could be simplified further as discussed.